# How to know the bluetooth device type in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth

I am using a [cordova plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-networking-bluetooth) to display the list of all bluetooth device . But I need to filter out all the devices which are printer. How can I do so ? Is there anyway I can find the bluetooth device type by their mac address or name ?

Comment: hey try this plugin https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

Answer (score 0):

As given in the documentation you mentioned.

```
var device_names = {};
var updateDeviceName = function (device) {
    device_names[device.address] = device.name;
};

// Add listener to receive newly found devices
networking.bluetooth.onDeviceAdded.addListener(updateDeviceName);

// With the listener in place, get the list of known devices
networking.bluetooth.getDevices(function (devices) {
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        updateDeviceName(devices[i]);
    }
});

// Now begin the discovery process.
networking.bluetooth.startDiscovery(function () {
    // Stop discovery after 30 seconds.
    setTimeout(function () {
        networking.bluetooth.stopDiscovery();
    }, 30000);
});
```

Check out here: [Device information and discovery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-networking-bluetooth#device-information-and-discovery)

Comment: Thanks for answering , but how do I know which devices are printer ?

Comment: From the name you should get some clue about the device type.

Comment: Yeah I can get clue , but I can't be sure .

Comment: @mW3 yeah i agree with you, what if two device have same name but not same type

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html still dont understand using it with cordova